# redirection while implementing a basic shell - malloc error

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to redirect the output of ls to a new file with fork and execvp. I've been trying to figure out this memory error:

```
malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

for a while now. when running the code below, msg is `"ls > /out.txt"` and the directory is the current environment.
When the function is run with these variables, the file `"out.txt"` is created with the words `"test4test5"` written on the top. My spaghetti code to get this output is:

```
void execute_redirect(char* msg, char* directory) {
    char s[2] = ">";
    int file;
    int pid;
    char *args[512];
    int i = 0;
    char str[50];
    char* str2;

    while(msg[i] != '>') {
        str[i] = msg[i];
        i++;
    }

    str2 = strtok(str, s); //so str2 = "ls"
    args[0] = str2;
    args[1] = NULL;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {

        perror("fork");

    } else if (pid == 0) {
        file = open(directory, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if (file < 0) {
            perror("open");
        }
        myPrint("test3");
        dup2(file, STDOUT_FILENO);
        myPrint("test4");
        close(file);
        myPrint("test5");
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
            perror("execvp");
        }
        _exit(1);
    } else {
        waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where the memory overwrite or corruption is coming from. I've tried setting `*args[512]` to `*args[2]` and `*args[1000]` but that didn't change anything. With string, too, 50 chars should be more than enough? So I have no idea what's going on. Any suggestions?

Comment: In `while(msg[i] != '>')`, the condition is true also for the NUL-byte at the end of the string.

Comment: Fixed it! How did you know @G.Sliepen?? why would that lead to a malloc error, if I may ask?

Comment: after `strtok()`, try printing str2 with `\"%s\"`, there may be a trailing space, and lead to an `execvp()` error; a small `args[]` should be OK.  BTW, you want to `open()` a regular file and not a `directory`, right?

Comment: Yep that's just lazy wording, and there was a trailing space...thanks @Milag.

Comment: Overrunning msg[] can cause your program to trounce all over your process memory.  Starting with whatever immediately follows msg[].

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Study the source code of *existing* open source shells, notably  [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) and [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating your strings correctly.

```
    char s[2] = ">";
    int i = 0;
    char str[50];
    char* str2;

    while(msg[i] != '>') {
        str[i] = msg[i];
        i++;
    }

    str2 = strtok(str, s); //so str2 = "ls"
    args[0] = str2;
    args[1] = NULL;
```

In your while loop you only copy up to (and not including) the `>` character and do not place a terminating `0` byte afterterwards. This leads to `str` not being a valid C string.
You also do not copy the `'>'` character itself.

This means that `str` will contain something like this: `"ls<garbage><garbage>....`.
Local variables are not zero filled and when you try to use that array with string functions you can easily run out of bounds of your array.

Similar problem will happen if you do not find a `'>'` in the input buffer at all. You will happily copy all the memory you can get hold of into your buffer, not stopping at the end of the string. That is what @G. Sliepen already mentioned in the comments.

Then your next problem is splitting the string using `strtok`.
As `str` does not contain the `'>'` at all, you will get a pointer to the whole string that is reachable in `str` which is not properly terminated and wherever a `'>'` is finally found, the `strtok` places a terminating `0` byte.

That said, you have multiple crash scenarious:

1. You may copy way too much data into `str` which alters content of other variables.
2. If you copy less data then fits into `str` you can still corrupt memory when `strtok` places a 0 in some invalid address.

If you don't crash immediately, you corrupt other data that can affect buffers allocated by `malloc` and that can in the end corrupt heap management leading to your assertion.

BTW:
Why do you use `strtok` at all? You only copy up to the `'>'` and there cannot be anything left in the string anyway.